# table items_item has no column named category_id

Tags: python, django

While creating item I got this error, though I can see `category_id` at `sqlall`:

```
table items_item has no column named category_id
```

migration commands:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations items
No changes detected

$ python manage.py migrate
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="item_images")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    show_in_front_page= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    always_show_in_front_page= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_trending=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

sqlall

```
# $ python manage.py sqlall items
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "items_category" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "items_item" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "description" text,
    "image" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "items_category" ("id"),
    "show_in_front_page" bool NOT NULL,
    "always_show_in_front_page" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_trending" bool NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE INDEX "items_item_6f33f001" ON "items_item" ("category_id");

COMMIT;
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Item, Category


admin.site.register(Item)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

Comment: Have you added the "category" field since you initially created the model and not done a [migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/)?

Comment: migration command returns no No migrations to apply.

Comment: How about "makemigrations"?

Comment: Can you show the migration that creates the Item model. Does it include the `category_id` field? Also, show the output of `./manage.py showmigrations`.

Comment: Note that sqlall shows you the `CREATE TABLE` statements if you wanted to create the table from scratch. It has no idea about the state of the table in your database.

Answer (score 3):

If the `category_id` column is already in an applied migration file, but hasn't been created in the database., then the easiest fix would be to add the column manually. It's easy to work out the SQL from your sqlall output above.

```
./manage.py dbshell # open a db shell

# Add the column
ALTER TABLE items_item ADD COLUMN "category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "items_category" ("id");
# Add the index
CREATE INDEX "items_item_6f33f001" ON "items_item" ("category_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

try deleting your db.sqlite3 file.
Then run makemigrations and migrate (the sqlite file will generates automatically).